# Can I assert a service is current without double-starting it the first time?

Tags: ansible

I often write this patterns when I want to make a role for a service (I'm using Mongo for this example, but it's the same with any other service like Nginx, MySQL, Redis, Bind, ElasticSearch, etc etc). The logic that I want to implement is:

- If the service is not started, start it
- Else, if the service is already started

  - If some configuration has changed since it started, restart
  - Else, do nothing (the service is already running and current)

When I write this in Ansible, I do it like this:

**roles/mongo/tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: Install Mongo
  yum:
    name: mongodb-org
    state: present
- name: Configure mongo
  template:
    src: mongod.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/mongod.conf
  notify:
    - restart mongod
- name: Start Mongo
  service:
    name: mongod
    state: started
```

**roles/mongo/handlers/main.yml**

```
---
- name: restart mongod
  service:
    name: mongod
    state: restarted
```

However, this doesn't quite follow what I wrote above. The logic for the above code is

- If the service is not started, start it
- If any configuration changed, even if it changed before we started the service, then restart the service

The result is that the first time I run my playbook, I

- Install Mongo
- Configure Mongo
- Start Mongo
- Restart Mongo

I wish I could skip that last restart. In my head, I think that the "Start Mongo" task should clear the "restart mongod" handler.

Is there any way to cancel a handler notification?

Or, is there a better way to write my playbook to achieve the logic that I actually want?

Comment: OK, I've changed to use a concrete example. Maybe that will be clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought `yum` leaves the service in the running state. That said, the solution is to flush handlers before `Start Mongo` task.